# Combining an image and shapefile in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I've been trying to combine an image produced from a deforestation database called Hansen and a shapefile created in ArcGIS to make a georeference image. The script I've written so far is below but unable to figure out how to combine the two (I've tried several scripts including http://uk.mathworks.com/help/map/examples/creating-maps-using-mapshow.html?searchHighlight=overlay%20maps). Any assistance would be helpful!

Thank you,
Michelle

```
% Read in thresholded Hansen data 
Data_FrenchGuiana = imread('FrenchGuiana_GFC_extract_thresholded.tif');
LossYear_FrenchGuiana = Data_FrenchGuiana(:,:,2); 
LossYear_FrenchGuiana = double(LossYear_FrenchGuiana); 
figure('color','white'); 
image(LossYear_FrenchGuiana) 
imwrite(A,'LossYear_FrenchGuiana.tif') 
country = shaperead('FrenchGuiana.shp'); 
figure mapshow(country); 
xlabel('easting in meters') 
ylabel('northing in meters')
```

Comment: Thank you for editing the script's display, Rodrigo. I still require information on combining the shapefile and LossYear_FrenchGuiana data.